# How to send an HTTP or HTTPS request through multiple proxy servers using python's mechanize module?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code in python using the mechanize module,
I want my http or https request to first go through several different proxies
before requesting the web page.
How can I accomplish this ?

I have try this so far:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# Proxy
br.set_proxies({"http": "myproxy.example.com:3128", "http": "another.proxy.net:3128"})

# Open some site, let's pick a random one, the first that pops in mind:
r = br.open('http://google.com')
html = r.read()
```

But, I have notice that the request is going only through one proxy server(always the last one in the dictionnary), so my question is, How can I make the request pass through those two proxies?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello Yuriy, I just updated the question.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to chain proxies, you're going to need to use the `CONNECT` method. This is usually ACLed to limit mischief, but the default configuration file allows most ports over 1024 and a handful below.

Comment: hello MattH, thanks for your reply. The CONNECT method from which module?